# What does "< <(command args)" mean in the shell?

Tags: bash, shell, built-in

When looping recursively through folders with files containing spaces the shell script I use is of this form, copied from the [internet](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020):

```
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
      dosomethingwith "$file"        # do something with each file
    done < <(find /bar -name *foo* -print0)
```

I think I understand the IFS bit, but I don't understand what the '`< <(...)`' characters mean. Obviously there's some sort of piping going on here.

It's very hard to Google "< <" or "<(", you see. I tried "angle bracket parenthesis" and "less-than parenthesis" but didn't find anything.

Comment: "man sh" is your friend, in any case.

Comment: It's not `< <` but it's the `<` and the `<(...)` operator, if i remember right

Comment: `dosomething "$file"` is definitely misleading. the reason why this construct was used is because in the original page an array was modified inside the loop

Comment: thanks for editing the question Jonathan. Realising that the pattern is "< <(..)", not "< <" makes a lot of difference.

Comment: I think, for better understanding and recall, that the "process substitution" operator should be called the penguin operator

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`<()` is called [**process substitution**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) in the manual, and is similar to a pipe but passes an argument of the form `/dev/fd/63` instead of using stdin.

`<` reads the input from a file named on command line.

*Together*, these two operators function exactly like a pipe, so it could be rewritten as

```
find /bar -name *foo* -print0 | while read line; do
  ...
done
```

Comment: it's not the same if you must not start a subshell

Comment: +1 because you have the correct name for the notation.  As @knittl points out, it is not quite identical to your rewrite because the loop will run in a sub-shell, and any changes made in the variables by the loop only affect the sub-shell, not the main script.  You can deal with that by redirecting the output of 'find' into '`{ while ...; do ...; done; ...rest of script...; }`', using the braces to group the whole of the rest of the script - loop and other material - into a single sub-shell.

Comment: thanks for that. I can feel my skull expanding over the part of the brain that does shell scripting. Having a precise term to google makes it much easier. Now I'm going to go find out what a subshell is.

Answer (score 26):

<( command ) is process substitution. Basically, it creates a special type of file called a "named pipe," then redirects the output of the command to be the named pipe. So for example, suppose you want to page through a list of files in an extra-big directory. You could do this:

```
ls /usr/bin | more
```

Or this:

```
more <( ls /usr/bin )
```

But NOT this:

```
more $( ls /usr/bin )
```

The reason for this becomes clear when you investigate further:

```
~$ echo $( ls /tmp )
gedit.maxtothemax.436748151 keyring-e0fuHW mintUpdate orbit-gdm orbit-maxtothemax plugtmp pulse-DE9F3Ei96ibD pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n ssh-wKHyBU1713 virtual-maxtothemax.yeF3Jo
~$ echo <( ls /tmp )
/dev/fd/63
~$ cat <( ls /tmp )
gedit.maxtothemax.436748151
keyring-e0fuHW
mintUpdate
orbit-gdm
orbit-maxtothemax
plugtmp
pulse-DE9F3Ei96ibD
pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n
ssh-wKHyBU1713
virtual-maxtothemax.yeF3Jo
```

/dev/fd/whatever acts like a text file with the output of the command between the parenthesis.

Comment: `more <( ls /usr/bin )` shows `/dev/fd/11 is not a regular file (use -f to see it)` on my zsh and shows `/dev/fd/63 is not a regular file (use -f to see it)` on my bash.

Comment: The second shell should be `more < <(ls /usr/bin)`, since `<(ls /usr/bin)` converts stdout to file and return file path as args and ` < ` receives file path and convert it to stdin.

Answer (score 4):

`<` redirects to stdin.

`<()` seems to be some sort of a reverse pipe, as mentioned on the page:

```
find /bar -name *foo* -print0 | \
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
  dosomethingwith "$file"        # do something with each file
done
```

will not work, because the while loop will be executed in a subshell, and you'll lose changes made in the loop

Comment: This answer would benefit from an x-ref to 'process substitution' and a URL such as http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution that explains it.  The key point is the sub-shell and changes made to variables in the sub-shell.  The other way of dealing with it is: `find ... | { while ...; do ...; done; ...rest of script...; }`, using the braces to run all the rest of the script in a sub-shell instead of just the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You use the process substitution construct (as per https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) mostly when you need to pass a file to a command but using the output of another command instead of a file, thus avoiding the need to create and populate that file in advance.

For ex. say that you want to compare the output of 2 commands, you can do like this:

`diff <(command1) <(command2)`

Comment: This question already has a similar accepted answer!

Comment: Yes but it doesn’t explain at all why it could convenient to use such a construct