# What does this notation mean in bash?

Tags: bash, process-substitution, dot-source

I am pretty sure this will be a duplicate, because I have seen it sometimes at other places, but I do not remember where and I also (obviously) do not know how it is called.

In an other SO post, there is this piece of code (bash):

```
obj(){
    . <(sed "s/obj/$1/g" obj.class)
}
```

What does `. <` do ?  If it has a name, what is it ?

Comment: Two different things. `<()` is **process substitution** where the output of the command inside is connected to a file that's usually an argument to another command. The period is an alias for `source`. They're both explained more in the bash manual.

Comment: It takes the file `obj.class` and replaces every occurrence of `obj` in that file with the parameter you pass to this function. It then `sources` the result into your current shell.

Comment: Also note that if you're still stuck on bash 3, this won't work. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32596123/9952196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Source `.` <sup>[[Docs]](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html)</sup>

> Read and execute commands from the filename argument in the current shell context.
>
> `source` is a synonym for dot/period `.` in bash, **but not in** POSIX sh, so for maximum compatibility use the period.

- [What's the meaning of a dot before a command in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114301/339347)

---

#### Process Substitution `< ()` <sup>[[Docs]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)</sup>

> Process substitution allows a process’s input or output to be referred to using a filename.

- [What does "< <(command args)" mean in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443085/what-does-command-args-mean-in-the-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Type this into your terminal:

```
help .
```

The function `obj` takes one argument. It executes `sed` and replaces all occurrences of `obj` in the file `obj.class` with the argument. The result is used as Bash code and gets evaluated by the running Bash instance.