# What is the `<( )` syntax in shell / bash, and how do I search for it?

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc, process-substitution

What is the `<( )` syntax in shell / bash, and how do I search for it (meaning: what's it called)?

Is this related to the ["heredoc"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697688/how-to-cat-eof-a-file-containing-code) syntax?

Example: [Pass a password to ssh in pure bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454037/pass-a-password-to-ssh-in-pure-bash/24455773#24455773)

```sh
sshpass -f <(printf '%s\n' your_password) ssh user@hostname
```

UPDATE: see: [What does "< <(command args)" mean in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443085/what-does-command-args-mean-in-the-shell/2443120#2443120)

Comment: My follow-up question: [Unix & Linux: `-sh: syntax error: unexpected "("` when attempting process substitution on an embedded Linux device with `bash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676676/sh-syntax-error-unexpected-when-attempting-process-substitution-on-an-e)

Comment: Don't ask this in a comment. Comments are not searchable on Stackoverflow. Post a new question instead.

Comment: @user1934428, my comment above is a _link_ to my follow-up question. It is already a new question I posted.

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`:

> **Process substitution** allows a process's input or output to be referred to using a filename.  It takes the form of
> <(list) or >(list).  The process list is run asynchronously, and its input or output appears as a filename.  This
> filename  is passed as an argument to the current command as the result of the expansion. [...]