# What is the difference between having `<` or `< <` after the `done` of a `while` loop? [Bash]

Tags: bash, io-redirection, ifs

I am new with Bash, and I am extending a script made by third parts.

In the following code snippet:

```
while IFS='|' read my_var
do
    (
     # commands based on $my_var
    ) &
done < <(psql my_db "SELECT ...")
```

I do not undertstand what `< <` does.

If `< <` were `<`, I would say the snippet would do:

- run the `SELECT...` query on `my_db`.
- take the result of the query ( a string of elements separated by `|` ) and store time by time each element in `my_var`.
- run in parallel the commands inside every while loop, using each time a different value for `my_var`.

Is this correct?
How does having `< <` instead of `<` change things ?

Comment: `<` is one piece of syntax. `<(  )` is another. They do two different things, but can be usefully combined. `< <` is not a piece of meaningful syntax, but `<` is, and so is `<( )`.

Comment: To understand the _why_, see [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: ...whereas to understand the `while read` in general, see [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: (I'm working on finding better duplicates -- this is a frequently-asked question, but it's not easy to search for).

Comment: Thanks in advance @CharlesDuffy

Comment: "Read into shell variables from a pipe" added as an extra duplicate because it's effectively a local equivalent to BashFAQ #24, describing the problem that motivates use of this construct instead of piping into the loop.

Comment: ...for a more detailed description of `<( )`, btw, https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst is an excellent resource. As you can see from `echo <(ls)`, `<( )` evaluates to a file; the other `<` redirects from that file.

Comment: hi @CharlesDuffy I just found out this question is also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/2443120/7658051 , that was pretty much what I was looking for but I could not find it since search engines return very different results for `done < <( ...)`

Comment: Thanks; added that one to the duplicate list.